# Dell Supplemental Pack Xenserver 6.5

Tags: dell, xenserver, dell-openmanage, out-of-band-management

I'm running **xenserver 6.5 SP1** on my **Poweredge M620**. I want to take advantage of the **remote host power on/off** features but it looks like I need to install a Dell Supplemental Package.

I've been seeing a lot of people mention installing **Open Manage Server Administrator** and others are saying to install this **RACADM** driver(?). Can somebody please point me in the right direction - OMSA vs. RACADM? Any additional links would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The M620 is a blade server. The entire OOB management will be residing on the management board(s) of the chassis (M1000e?).

This seems to be iDRAC too, just as with Dell's standalone machines, so [XenServer's documentation on remote host poweron](http://docs.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/6.5.0/1.0/en_gb/reference.html#id531063) still applies which tells you to install the Dell supplemental pack ***as well as the RACADM command line utility***.

Comment: I reinstalled xenserver 6.5 and added the opemanage 8.1 supplemental pack during the install process which worked this time. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: This was the iso I found and used for 6.5: http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=212KT. I plan on upgrading to 7.1 in the near future, I'm hoping the same iso will work as well.